# Count particular words used in a variable?

Tags: javascript, iterator

Currently working on a CodeAcademy JS project.

```
let story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s really an adventure from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a really long way left to go. After a quick photo op at the very popular Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge into New Jersey.  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already very tired by the time I got to the other side.  An hour later, I reached Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of the Hudson.  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end of the route you actually cross back into New York! At this point, you are very close to the end.';

let overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];
```

The question is "You want to let the user of your program know how many times they have used these overused words."

Struggling to get it, a hint was to use an If Else statement but not sure how to exactly.

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to let the user know how many times they have used the overusedWords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s really an adventure from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a really long way left to go. After a quick photo op at the very popular Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge into New Jersey.  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already very tired by the time I got to the other side.  An hour later, I reached Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of the Hudson.  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end of the route you actually cross back into New York! At this point, you are very close to the end.';
var overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];

var used = {};
story.split(/[\s,]+/).forEach(item => {
    if (overusedWords.indexOf(item) >= 0) {
        if (!used[item]) {
            used[item] = 1
        }
        else {
         used[item] = used[item]+ 1   
        }
    }
});


console.log(JSON.stringify(used));
```

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot

Comment: @conye9980 , Great to know that it helped you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use regular expressions to find the overused words:

```
> story.match(/\b(really|very|basically)\b/g).length
8
```

This will look for anything that is either `really`, `very` or `basically` and is a single word (`\b` is the word delimiter).

Note that `match` may return `null`, so you should check for that before querying the length.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use string split method. Also you need to replace all commas.

```
var array = story.replace(/,/g , "").split(' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code.

```js
let story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s really an adventure from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a really long way left to go. After a quick photo op at the very popular Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge into New Jersey.  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already very tired by the time I got to the other side.  An hour later, I reached Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of the Hudson.  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end of the route you actually cross back into New York! At this point, you are very close to the end.';

let overusedWords = ['really', 'very', 'basically'];
function getCount(){
for(var i=0; i<overusedWords.length;i++){
alert(overusedWords[i]+" word count: "+story.split(overusedWords[i]).length);
}
}
```

```html
<input type ="button" value="test" onclick="getCount()"/>
```